# Trying to identify this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone help me identify what kind of beetle this is?

It's ~1/4" in size and was found on some air-dried hardwood lumber in the Pacific Northwest.

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a hemipteran than a beetle: You can see that the rear part of the wings is membranous. There also seems to be a rostrum starting from the front of the head. https://australianmuseum.net.au/what-are-the-differences-between-bugs-and-beetles

Comment: thanks for helping! I think you're right;  it looks like it might be some sort of chinch bug.

Comment: I am reasonably certain we have a member of superfamily Lygaeoidea here, but which of the many families that group now contains (aside from Berytidae; the stiltlike legs of that group are clearly not present here) is represented cannot be ascertained from the evidence we have available.